# How do I access composable state from a module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-modules, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to pass state value of `number` from one store to another, why it isn't working? Getting number is not defined.

```js
import {
  reactive,
  toRefs
} from 'vue';
  
const state = reactive({
  number: 12
})

export function test() {
  
  return {
    ...toRefs(state)
  }
}
```

to this:

```js
import {
  reactive,
  toRefs,
} from 'vue';

import { test } from '@/myvuex/somestore';

const state = reactive({
  testValue: 5
})

export function useGlobal() {

  console.log(number)

  return {
    ...toRefs(state),
    test,
    number
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting to see `12` in the console?

Comment: @shob yes, I want to transfer the state to other store, in vuex I always used rootState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test` import is a function, so it has to be called.  It returns an object containing the refs of the first module's `state`.

Then you can pass on the object's `number` property:

```js
const importedState = test();         // retrieving the state from module #1
const number = importedState.number;  // the `number` ref
    
export function useGlobal() {
  console.log(number.value);          // It's a ref now, use `.value`
      
  return {
    ...toRefs(state),
    test,
    number
  }
}
```